# How to update boolean in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, boolean, mern

I have a `boolean` that I need to update in `mongoDB` depending on if the user/restaurant is active or not. Is there any way to do this? this is what I have so far

**The Schema - simplified**

```
const ownerSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  foodType: { type: String, required: true },
  location: { type: Array, default: [] },

  active: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});
```

**And the controller:**

```
  isActive: function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
db.Owners.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id })
  .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
  .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
 },
```

I just need an easy way to change it to true and false. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
db.Owners.update({ _id: req.params.id },{"$set":{"active":false}})
  .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
  .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
 },
```

Comment: This works thanks! Is there any way to make an if statement of some sort so If it's false it will change to true, and if its true it will change to false, or do I just have to do them separately?

Comment: You need to handle it separately using logic, while mongo update is just to update. Mark and upvote if the answer helped